# How do I properly edit the values shown into the grid?

Tags: angular

This will definitely be kind of a simple question.

```
     {
    headerName: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
    sortable: false,
    lockPosition: true,
    resizable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'isShopOpen',
    field: 'isShopOpen',
    sortable: false,
    lockPosition: true,
    resizable: true
  }
```

I have this example table, and I'd like to know what's the best way for having it showing "Closed" if isShopOpen === 1, "Opened" if isShopOpen === 2, "Temporarily Closed" is isShopOpen === 3.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Use conditions with `ngIf` https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: I can't really use ngIf for the table. It's a component that, given the properties, has no reference to the actual datas in html.
The condition should definitely be something in the TS file.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzjn1n) One way is custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'header',
   pure: false
})
export class PersonelFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(param: any): any { 
     if(param==1){return "Closed"}
     else if(param==2){return "Opened"}
     else if(param==3){return "Temporarily Closed"}
     else {return ""}
   }
}
```

in html give like `isShopOpen | header` to html bind

```
{{isShopOpen |  header }}
```

Comment: I can't really use stuff in html. It's a component that, given the properties, has no reference to the actual datas in html. The condition should definitely be something in the TS file.

Comment: Okey then in your data where u get from server add one more attributes there and assign value with your condition

Answer (score 0):

another way is process the value by passing it to method and display the return value.
In your .ts file

```
generateShopOpenDisplay(param){
     if(param==1){return "Closed"}
     else if(param==2){return "Opened"}
     else if(param==3){return "Temporarily Closed"}
     else{ return ''}
}
```

and call it

```
{{generateShopOpenDisplay(isShopOpen)}}
```

Comment: dont use function for angular like that ! That is bad for performance. Functions always listen html.

Comment: This throws an error, field can't accept a function. And "field" is the only place I have the value of isShopOpen.